# How to show x-axis and y-axis for histogramSlider jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the link https://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Histogram-Slider-Plugin-jQuery.html from where I am gathering knowledge fro histogram slider. Need to show x-axis and y-axis for the graph slider. Please guide me with your valuable suggestions.[image]

Comment: Looking at the plugin, i'm not sure if there is any support for x/y axis. Have you seen any examples of this plugin with x/y axis?

Comment: No I have searched it, but did not get any examples, need to implement one histogram slider using third party libraries. I have just got this plugin only.Any suggestions from your end how to do this with x/y axis?